# Terraform: providers with dependencies on resources

Tags: terraform

I've encountered various problems with providers that depend on other resources.

Databricks example:

- azurerm_databricks_workspace resource
- databricks provider depends on azurerm_databricks_workspace
- databricks_cluster uses databricks provider

Kubernetes example:

- azurerm_kubernetes_cluster resource
- kubectl or helm provider depends on azurerm_kubernetes_cluster resource
- kubectl_manifest resource uses kubectl provider

If I make a change that requires the base resource (e.g., Databricks workspace, AKS cluster) to be destroyed and re-created, Terraform can't handle the resources downstream managed by the provider.  The resources within the Databricks workspace or AKS cluster are in TF state, but the provider is impacted by changing the base resource.

The provider is unable to then manage the existing resources associated with the provider pre-change; [this article explains the errors with Kubernetes](https://itnext.io/terraform-dont-use-kubernetes-provider-with-your-cluster-resource-d8ec5319d14a), and I've seen similar issues in Databricks like the provider unable to authenticate to the existing workspace.

The workaround I see is to break the direct dependency between the providers and other resources: i.e., create your Databricks workspace then use `data` with a `depends_on` to look up the created workspace for the provider.

But IMO that negates one of the best parts of using Terraform to manage Databricks or Kubernetes resources -- seamless chaining resource dependencies together by reference.

Is there a way to get Terraform to do this automatically?